# Getting yellow background-color in chrome around anchor, tried all the solution available, but still no fix

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome, styled-components

I tried all the solutions from forums, still not fixed. I am creating a combo box using styled-component in React.

[image]

above box.

The problem is chrome has added its own background color.

code:

```
<Wrapper>
          
          <SelectWrapper>
      
             <VisibleLabel>Year</VisibleLabel>
       
            <Select
                onChange={(e) => {
                  onSelectChange(e);
                }}
            >
                {years.map((y) => (
                  <Option key={y.value} value={y.value}>
                    {y.year}
                  </Option>
                ))}
              </Select>
            <ChevronIcon
              id="chevron-down"
              size={24}
              strokeWidth={1.5}
            />
          </SelectWrapper>
        </Wrapper>
```

styled-component:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: -30px;
  background: ${COLORS.gray[100]};
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  
`;

const SelectWrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  isolation: isolate;
`;
const VisibleLabel = styled.a`
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 110px;
  bottom: 10;
  margin: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  z-index: 2;
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  filter: none;
  background-color: transparent !important;
`;


const Select = styled.select`
  position: relative;
  appearance: none;
  filter: none;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 12px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  autocomplete: off;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 4;
  

  & > :focus {
    outline: 0;
    outline-color: transparent;
    outline-style: none;
  }
`;
```

I tried adding !important, webkits, etc but still no results. Please if anyone will be kind enough to help. thanks

in chrome, the source is:

```
<gistnote class="gistnote-highlight" highlightid="6573e94f-c486-43c1-bef0-541b6045843d" colornum="3" style="background-color: rgb(255, 251, 120);" id="6573e94f-c486-43c1-bef0-541b6045843d">Year</gistnote>

CSS:
element.style{
   background-color: rgb(255, 251, 120);
}
```

Comment: That looks exactly like the text search. Are you sure you did not leave it open by accident?

Comment: try to add text-decoration: none to anchor

Comment: @thinkgruen sorry didn't understand.

Comment: @Castle i have added already above, didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One sidenote: I find it very difficult to read StyledComponents and I try to avoid them as much as possible.

There are 2 things. `VisibleLabel` should not be an `<a>`-tag, but a `label`. You want it to select the Selectbox, not link to something else.

Have you seen this short article? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers/
That might point you in the right direction.

Another possibility is a chome plugin causing troubles.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah it was stupid chrome plugin that caused it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add in `css` file? Because your `styled-components` makes `local` changes, not [global](https://scalablecss.com/styled-components-global-styles/). Try to add it as global

Comment: I did in global styles

Comment: can you share your code in `codesandbox`? And also are you sure that the problem occurs only chrome? Did you run your server on Firefox?

Comment: Yes the problem only occurs in chrome. I did ran it in firefox.